# Windows Server 2008 Terminal Server CALs and Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, licensing, cal

Recently we have have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on one of our development boxes at work. We have 10 Client Access Licence's for Microsoft Windows Terminal Server 2008. I'm under the impression that these licences will entitle us to have 10 concurrent connections to Remote Desktop. At the moment we are only allowed two.

Can we have a RD connection per CAL? If so - how do we configure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to install the role "Remote Desktop Session Host" on your server to enable more than two simultaneous connections to a server.